# Android Room NOT NULL columns

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite, android-room

I'm having some trouble with `NOT NULL` columns using `Android Room`. I'm already using `@android.support.annotation.NonNull` annotation, but it's not working as expected. The problem is following:

I have a data structure that is built over time. That means that constructor doesn't build the final instance. But some fields that must have a `NOT NULL` constraint in database aren't initialized in the constructor. Therefore they would have a `null` value for some period of time. But `Android Studio` doesn't seem to like it. There are warnings `Not-null fields must be initialized` all over the place.

Is there any other annotation that I could use instead of the one mentioned above so the `NOT NULL` constraint applies to database columns but not to the fields defined in my Java code?

Following example describes the problem a little bit better I think:

I have a table `transaction` and a column `amount` in it which has a `NOT NULL` constraint. When constructing a new `transaction` in my code I don't have the amount available yet. I want to assign it later. But that doesn't mean this field is supposed to be `NULL`'able in database.

So what could be the best solution in this case?

Answer (score 0):

If you use `@NonNull` annotation, then as you have found, the value cannot be null at any level. That is, the annotation is not a Room annotation but an Android annotation.

In regard to Room, it determines the column types and constraints, by inspecting the classes annotated with @Entity, if they are in the list of entities defined via the entities parameter of the @Database annotation.

In regards to the NOT NULL constraint then some rules apply.

- If the type of the field/member variable is a Java primitive, as Java primitives cannot be null, then the NOT NULL constraint is implied and thus applied.
- If the type of the field/member variable is an Object (e.g. `Long` as opposed to  `long`), then there is no implicit NOT NULL unless constructors come into play.
- If the field/member variable is of an integer type (int, Integer, long Long ....) AND it is annotated with @PrimaryKey then convenience @Insert method caters then,
- for a 0 value in the case of primitives to be a skipped value (no value specified) and thus generated as is a feature of SQLite.
- for a null value in the case of Objects (Integer, Long ....) for the value to be skipped and thus generated.

For example consider:-

```
@Entity
class Transaction {
    @PrimaryKey
    Long id=null;
    long timestamp;
    Long alt_timestamp;
    double amount;
    Double alt_amount;
    ....
```

This when compiled with the appropriate @Database annotated class that extends RoomDatabase results in the following SQL being generated:-

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Transaction` (`id` INTEGER, `timestamp` INTEGER NOT NULL, `alt_timestamp` INTEGER, `amount` REAL NOT NULL, `alt_amount` REAL, PRIMARY KEY(`id`))
```

- as can be seen, the columns for primitives (timestamp and amount) have the NOT NULL constraint coded, whilst for the Object based columns (alt_timestamp and alt_amount) the NOT NULL constrain is not coded.
- when a project is compiled with an @Database annotation then java code is generated. The code can be located from the Android View in the Java(generated) the class will be the same as the class that is annotated with @Database but suffixed with **_Impl**.

If, for example

```
@NonNull 
Long alt_timestamp;
```

is used then the SQL changes to include the NOT NULL constraint e.g.

```
.... `alt_timestamp` INTEGER NOT NULL` ....
```

These are rules that are imposed.

So in response to ***Is there any other annotation that I could use instead of the one mentioned above so the NOT NULL constraint applies to database columns but not to the fields defined in my Java code?***

**NO.**

However, you could, *remembering that the NOT NULL constraint is applied to the column(s) in the database*, have constructors that allow nulls. Perhaps consider the following that may suit:-

```
@Entity
class Transaction {
    @PrimaryKey
    Long id=null;
    long timestamp;
    @NonNull
    Long alt_timestamp;
    double amount;
    Double alt_amount;

    Transaction(){}

    @Ignore
    Transaction (Long id, Long timestamp, Long alt_timestamp, Double amount, Double alt_amount) {
        this.id = id;
        if (timestamp==null) timestamp=0L; /* effectively the default value is 0 (could be otherwise to suit) */
        this.timestamp = timestamp; 
        this.alt_timestamp = alt_timestamp; /* can be null BUT if alt_timestamp is @NOTNULL annotated then NOT NULL constraint conflict */
        if (amount==null) amount=0.0D;
        this.amount=amount;
        this.alt_amount=alt_amount;
    }
}
```

- the `@Ignore` annotation is telling Room NOT to use this constructor, so it will always use the default constructor when creating a Transaction object.